# @synthesize in Xcode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode 4.4's description, it said:

- In Objective-C `@synthesize` command is generated by default when using properties.

It means: I do not need to write `@synthesize` any more **OR** Xcode would auto-fill `@synthesize` for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to write `@synthesize` anymore - just try it yourself!

[Article reference](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html):

> With Xcode 4.4 and LLVM Compiler 4.0 the @synthesize directive is no longer required as it will be provided by default. That means in most cases you now only need the @property and the compiler takes care of everything else for you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here is Apple's publication covering it [Objective-C Feature Availability Index](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012243)
which states:

> **Default synthesis of @property instance variables and accessor methods:**
>   Xcode 4.4
>   (LLVM Compiler 4.0)